# Populate @Transient field within Spring Data Jpa Repository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Is possible to populate transient field in entity class with Spring Data REST api somehow (by projection or something) - to get that value in JSON response ? I need to populate for example `info` field with value got from second datasource (i had Spring repo bean for this datasource and need inject it in something like "interceptor" and fill that field).

```
@Entity
public class User {
   @Id
   private Long id;

   @Transient
   private String info;

   // getters & setters
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Comment: How do you want to populate it? Being transient means it'll only not be persisted in the DB, but the field is still usable

Answer (score 1):

I found solution using [PostLoadEventListener](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/spi/PostLoadEventListener.html), but it is for Hibernate, not exactly what i was looking for, but works. I think it should be more general Spring-ly solution.

```
@Component
public class UserInterceptor implements PostLoadEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private SecondRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("prmiaryEntityManagerFactory")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        HibernateEntityManagerFactory hibernateEntityManagerFactory = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) this.entityManagerFactory;
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactoryImpl = (SessionFactoryImpl) hibernateEntityManagerFactory.getSessionFactory();
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactoryImpl.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_LOAD, this);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onPostLoad(PostLoadEvent event) {
        final Object entity = event.getEntity();
        if(entity != null && entity instanceof User) {
            User user = (User) entity;

            // populate using another repo bean
            Info s = repo.findOne(user.getInfoId());
            user.setInfo(s.getName());
        }
    }

}
```